# Socket.IO does not broadcasting to sender on first load in NextJS

Tags: javascript, sockets, next.js

beginner and first time poser here. So im trying to make a realtime chat app in Next using SocketIO and the problem i face is everytime the sender send a message, the receiver able to see it but not the sender. The problem only happens on first load, then when i reload the page both the sender and receiver able to see the messages. Can someone explain why?

**Chat.js**

```
import {useSocketIo} from "@/service/socket/useSocketIo";

const Chat = (props) => {
    const { socket } = props;
    const contex = useContext(RootContext)
    const {state, dispatch} = contex
    const [user, setUser] = useState("")
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

    useSocketIo(socket)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/api/socket').then(() => {
            console.log("Socket connected: " + socket.id)
        })

        getUserData().then((response) => {
            setUser(response)
            console.log(response)
        })
    },[])

    const sendMessage = () => {
        const data = {
            senderName: user.name,
            senderId: user.$id,
            message: message,
        }
        console.log(data)
        socket.emit("created-message", data);
        setMessage('');
    }

   return(
     <>
      {state.received_messages.map((item, i) => (
        item.senderId === user.$id ?
           <MessageBubble
            key={i}
            message={item.message}
           /> :
           <ChatBubble
            username={item.senderName}
            message={item.message}
           />
       ))}

       <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-x-5 w-full">
         <div className="w-5/6">
           <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="type here"
             value={message}
             onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="" onClick={sendMessage}>
             <ButtonIcon className="bg-secondary-teal p-5 rounded-full" img={send}/>
          </div>
       </div>
     </>
   )
}
```

**_app.js**

```
import { Context } from '@/service/context/Context'
import { Montserrat } from 'next/font/google'
import {initializeSocket} from "@/service/socket/client";

const montserrat = Montserrat({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  let socket = initializeSocket()
  return(
    <Context>
     <main className={montserrat.className}>
        <Component {...pageProps} socket={socket}/>
     </main>
    </Context>
  ) 
}
```

**socket.js**

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import messageHandler from "@/utils/messageHandler";

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Already set up");
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
  res.socket.server.io = io;

  const onConnection = (socket) => {
    messageHandler(socket);
  };

  io.on("connection", onConnection);

  console.log("Setting up socket");
  res.end();
}
```

**client.js**
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export const initializeSocket = () => {
let socket = io(`${process.env.BASE_URL}`);
socket.on('connect', () => {
console.log('Socket Connected! : ' + socket.id)
})

```
return socket;
```

};

**useSocketIo.js**

```
import {useContext, useEffect} from "react";
import {Action} from "@/service/enum/enumReducer";
import {RootContext} from "@/service/context/Context";


export const useSocketIo = (socket) => {
    const {dispatch} = useContext(RootContext)

    const addTranscriptResults = (transcripts) => {
        dispatch({type:Action.TEMP_MESSAGES.ADD, payload: transcripts})
    };

    const addReceivedMessages = (message) => {
        dispatch({type:Action.MESSAGE.ADD, payload: message})
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use socket io!")

        socket.on("incoming-message", (message) => {
            // Save to "received_messages" state to be displayed
            console.log(message)

            addReceivedMessages(message)
        })

        return () => {
            socket.off("incoming-message");
            socket.off("created-message");
        }
    }, []);

    return {
    }
}
```

**messageHandler.js**

```
export default (socket) => {
    const createdMessage = (message) => {
        socket.emit("incoming-message", message);
    };

    socket.on("created-message", createdMessage);
};
```